# SelectInput: How to make choices equal to the list of all data frame in current environment?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to write a shiny app with InputSelect widget that allows the user to pick a data frame object from the current session from the dropdown choices.

The codes below works when the choices for InputSelect are the mtcars or iris objects. How do I generalize the choice to all the data frame in my current session?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <-dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(box(selectInput('dflist', 'Choose Data Fame',choices=c('mtcars','Thiris')))),
    fluidRow(DTOutput('tbl'))
    )
```

)

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df=reactiveValues(df=NULL)
    observeEvent(input$dflist,{ 
    if (!is.null(input$dflist)){
       df$df =get(input$dflist)
    }
    })

output$tbl = renderDT(head(df$df))
}
```

## Run the application

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I have 3 data frames df1, df2 and df3 in my current session, I could manually replace c('mtcars','iris') with c('df1','df2','df3'). However, I would like to some codes to automate the process.

Thanks in advance for your help.

HHN

Comment: Are you looking for `updateselectinput`?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand:

```
objects <- setNames(ls(), ls())
dataframes <- names(Filter(is.data.frame, lapply(objects, get)))
```